# Is there a way of doing the cast from xsd:duration to xsd:time in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

For example I want to convert `PT1H5M14.000S` to `01:05:14`

Comment: I don't see any SPARQL support for neither `xsd:duration` nor `xsd:time`, thus, a conversion is probably not supported. See the [supported datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#operandDataTypes)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the duration to a "zero" time:

```
select * {
bind("PT1H5M14.000S"^^xsd:duration as ?x)
BIND("00:00:00"^^xsd:time + ?x as ?y) }
```

Comment: I'm wondering which SPARQL engine/triple store supports this? It's not part of the SPARQL specs.

Comment: @AKSW, Jena supports this kind of arithmetic (as well as many XPath functions), and also Blazegraph do.

Comment: Ok, but both are extensions, right? E.g. in Jena ARQ I know that there are additional functions (prefixed with `fn:`) If so, it would be good to make this clear in the answer. It's not clear which system he's using. And for example, in Virtuoso the query above doesn't work (at least not on the DBpedia endpoint).

Comment: @AKSW, I'm agree with you. BTW, [TL;DR](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2012Aug/0003.html).

Comment: It's a datatype extension. Jena supports XSD datatypes that make sense (i.e. no sequences, and not the XML specific datatypes). It also supports  F&O (functions and operators) v 3.0 except the picture syntax date/time formatters.